# Repeating frames (=freeze effect) while transcoding H264 MP4 creates odd artefacts

Tags: java, android, mp4, h.264, transcoding

I'm trying to achieve a freeze frame effect by repeating the same input frame for a few seconds while transcoding H264 to H264 video on a Java / Android platform. I modified  https://github.com/ypresto/android-transcoder/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/net/ypresto/androidtranscoder/engine/VideoTrackTranscoder.java so that I simply skip the android MediaExtractor.advance()

```
if(timeScaler.frozenAt==-1 ){
     mediaExtractor.advance();
}
else{
    freezeUsec +=  (1000/outputFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE)) *1000;
    return DRAIN_STATE_NONE;
}
return DRAIN_STATE_CONSUMED;
```

while the effect is active. My thinking was that this would just make the decoder and the encoder repeat the same data thus producing the desired effect. This works well but I get odd (compression?) artefacts in the frames following the freeze effect. It looks like parts of the frozen frame (arm + ball) gets stuck for seconds. The effect is minimal on some devices and really heavy on other (pictured below):

[image: MP4 artefacts]

Answer (score 0):

In H.264 only a small fraction of the frames in a video data stream are so-called I frames, also known as key frames or Instantaneous Decoder Refresh (IDR) frames. The rest are P (predictive) frames or B (interpolated) frames. In other words each decoded frame depends on the previous one.

If you suppress the decoding of P or B frames, or decode them repeatedly, you'll damage your decoded picture until the next I frame comes along.